# What font does N*E*R*D use for their logo?

Tags: font-identification

What is the name of this tech-ish, uppercase font that [N*E*R*D](http://n-e-r-d.com/) uses for their logo?

[image]

Hi I was just wondering what font style this is. If you could help me it would be great appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly the same, but likely inspired by [Xirod](http://www.dafont.com/xirod.font?text=NERD&fpp=100&back=theme):

[image: Xirod font sample]

The E is flipped veritcally and the R is slightly different as well.

Comment: Exactly the same. No any transformations: used CAPS and low case letters. http://www.fonts.com/font/typodermic/xirod/regular

Comment: @Ilan good find! I had suspected that might be the case and tested it, looks like the version I linked to on dafont is slightly different from yours.